# Spring Cloud Dataflow: how to persist stream definitions

Tags: spring-cloud-dataflow

I am using the [local server](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-dataflow/tree/master/spring-cloud-dataflow-server-local) of spring cloud dataflow. Each time I restart the server, all deployed apps and stream definitions are lost. How can I persist my stream definitions so that they survive server restarts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As of [RC1](https://spring.io/blog/2016/06/21/spring-cloud-data-flow-1-0-rc1-released), the stream/task/job definitions among other metadata specs can be [configured](http://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-dataflow/docs/1.0.0.RC1/reference/htmlsingle/#_datasource) to persist in an RDBMS, and there's support for many of the commonly used databases. If nothing is provided, the default embedded `h2` database is used, which is in-memory and it is recommended only for development purposes.

Comment: Thanks, Sabby! When I configure an embedded H2 database with file backend, start the local dataflow server and access the dashboard, I get Table "URI_REGISTRY" not found; SQL statement:
select NAME, URI from URI_REGISTRY [42102-191] - so seemingly the schema somehow is not initialized. Any clues?

Comment: Never mind, it's working now. I previously used https://start.spring.io/ to generate a local server spring boot application, which was missing the @EnableDataFlowServer annotation. With that annotation everything is working now. Thanks!